# How to get current working directory using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using MS Excel 2010 and trying to get the current directory using the below code,

```
    path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

But ActiveWorkbook.Path returns blank.

Comment: If the file hasn't yet been saved then there's no path to return. What do you mean by "current" directory?  If you just want the current *default* directory you can use `CurDir()`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

When one opens an Excel document `D:\db\tmp\test1.xlsm`:

- `CurDir()` returns `C:\Users\[username]\Documents`
- `ActiveWorkbook.Path` returns `D:\db\tmp`

So `CurDir()` has a system default and can be changed.

`ActiveWorkbook.Path` does not change for the same saved Workbook.

For example, `CurDir()` changes when you do "File/Save As" command, and select a random directory in the File/Directory selection dialog. Then click on Cancel to skip saving. But `CurDir()` has already changed to the last selected directory.

---

### [ADD]
Resume VBA for different applications

**Access** D:\db\tmp\test1.accdb, like duckboy81 commented:

1. CurDir() =>  C:\Users\[username]\Documents
2. Application.CurrentProject.Path => D:\db\tmp

**Excel** D:\db\tmp\test1.xlsm:

1. CurDir() =>  C:\Users\[username]\Documents
2. ActiveWorkbook.Path => D:\db\tmp
3. Application.DefaultFilePath => C:\Users\[username]\Documents

**Outlook**:

1. CurDir() =>  C:\WINDOWS\System32
2. Application.Session.Stores(1).Filepath => D:\programdata\Outlook\myOutlookDocX.pst

**PowerPoint** D:\db\tmp\test1.ppt:

1. CurDir() => C:\Users\[username]\Documents
2. ActivePresentation.Path => D:\db\tmp

**Word** D:\db\tmp\test1.docx:

1. CurDir()    => C:\Users\[username]\Documents
2. Application.ActiveDocument.Path => D:\db\tmp
3. Application.ActiveDocument.FullName => D:\db\tmp\test1.docx
4. Application.StartupPath => C:\users\[username]\appdata\roaming\microsoft\word\startup

Comment: When you use `Workbooks.Open("file.xls")` (without giving a path), does it assume `CurDir()` as the path?

Comment: For developers using MS Access: `Application.CurrentProject.Path`

Comment: @André Chalella, yes it's opened in CurDir() after code testing.

Answer (score 12):

You have several options depending on what you're looking for.
`Workbook.Path` returns the path of a saved workbook. `Application.Path` returns the path to the Excel executable. `CurDir` returns the current working path, this probably defaults to your My Documents folder or similar.

You can also use the windows scripting shell object's .CurrentDirectory property.

```
Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Debug.Print wshell.CurrentDirectory
```

But that should get the same result as just

```
Debug.Print CurDir
```

Answer (score 10):

It would seem likely that the ActiveWorkbook has not been saved...

Try `CurDir()` instead.

Comment: That is usually correct, unless Excel has been opened with an explicitly set alternative working directory.  If the active workbook has not been saved, then it is entirely up to you as to where it is to *be* saved.

Answer (score 5):

Your code: `path = ActiveWorkbook.Path`

returns blank because you haven't saved your workbook yet.

To overcome your problem, go back to the Excel sheet, save your sheet, and run your code again.

This time it will not show blank, but will show you the path where it is located (current folder)

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` for just the path itself (without the workbook name) or `Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName` for the path with the workbook name.

Answer (score 1):

This is the VBA that I use to **open the current path** in an **Explorer** window:

```
Shell Environ("windir") & "\explorer.exe """ & CurDir() & "",vbNormalFocus
```

---

**Microsoft Documentation**:

- [**`CurDir` Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/curdir-function)
- **[`Environ` Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function)**
- [**`Shell` Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function)

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean pure working Directory, this should suit for you.

**Solution A:**

```
Dim ParentPath As String: ParentPath = "\"
Dim ThisWorkbookPath As String
Dim ThisWorkbookPathParts, Part As Variant
Dim Count, Parts As Long

ThisWorkbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
ThisWorkbookPathParts = Split(ThisWorkbookPath, _
                        Application.PathSeparator)

Parts = UBound(ThisWorkbookPathParts)
Count = 0
For Each Part In ThisWorkbookPathParts
    If Count > 0 Then
        ParentPath = ParentPath & Part & "\"
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = Parts Then Exit For
Next

MsgBox "File-Drive = " & ThisWorkbookPathParts _
       (LBound(ThisWorkbookPathParts))
MsgBox "Parent-Path = " & ParentPath
```

But if don't, this should be enough.

**Solution B:**

```
Dim ThisWorkbookPath As String

ThisWorkbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
MsgBox "Working-Directory = " & ThisWorkbookPath
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple Example below:

```
Sub openPath()
Dim path As String
path = Application.ActivePresentation.path
Shell Environ("windir") & "\explorer.exe """ & path & "", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: The goal of the question is to understand what the current path is ***programmatically*** and get that into a variable. Your solution simply opens windows explorer to show the user what path is which is not useful as it can not be subsequently used programmatically. Also `ActivePresentation` is not a property of excel application so will not be compileable/runnable even

Answer (score -3):

Use these codes and enjoy it.

```
Public Function GetDirectoryName(ByVal source As String) As String()
Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection

Dim source_file() As String
Dim i As Integer        

queue.Add fso.GetFolder(source) 'obviously replace

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
    '...insert any folder processing code here...
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
    Next oSubfolder
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        '...insert any file processing code here...
        'Debug.Print oFile
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve source_file(i)
        source_file(i) = oFile
    Next oFile
Loop
GetDirectoryName = source_file
End Function
```

And here you can call function:

```
Sub test()
Dim s
For Each s In GetDirectoryName("C:\New folder")
Debug.Print s
Next
End Sub
```