# Go up one folder level

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro that gets sub folder data. However I also want something from the main folder.

I looked at [How to get current working directory using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824164/how-to-get-current-working-directory-using-vba) but need to change activeworkbook path:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path might be "c:\parent\subfolder"
```

I would want

```
"c:\parent\"
```

Using Excel 365 VBA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the path may not be the current working directory you need to extract the path from the string.

Find the last `\` and read all characters to the left:

```
ParentPath = Left$(Path, InStrRev(Path, "\"))
```

If you are working around the current directory `ChDir ".."` will jump you up one level, the new path can be returned by `CurrDir`.

Comment: I should say it will always be in the working directory (in this case!). But good to know!

Comment: Try it like this: Left$(application.ActiveWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(application.ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\")-1)

Comment: Thanks. Spotted I'd put the code a line to early as well! (On the main code)

Answer (score 8):

The most reliable way to do this is to use the Scripting.FileSystemObject.  It has a method that will get the parent folder without trying to parse it:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Debug.Print .GetParentFolderName(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)
End With
```

Comment: This gives you the `subfolder`, not the `parent` folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim WbDir As String
Dim OneLvlUpDir As String

'get current WorkBook directory
WbDir = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

'get directory one level up
ChDir WbDir
ChDir ".."

'print new working directory and save as string. Use as needed.
Debug.Print CurDir()
OneLvlUpDir = CurDir()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean this solution:

```
Sub t()
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MsgBox "ThisWorkbook.Path = " & ThisWorkbook.Path & vbLf & _
"Path one folder down = " & fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\." & "NewFolder").Path
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```